# how to get the css floating property to work with four divs?

Tags: css

how to get the css floating property to work with four divs? I have four divs I would like to get algin using the layout as an example,

```
                     div One     - div two
                     div Three   - div Four
```

Here is what I attempted using the following css and html code but not lining up correctly.

```
      <HTML>
      <HEAD>
      <TITLE>Layout Example</TITLE>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///C:/app3/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css">
      <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></SCRIPT>
      <style>
             .divs
             {
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
             }
             #one
             {
                background-color: black;
                float: left;
                color: white;
             }
             #two
             {
                background-color: blue;
                float: left;
             }
             #three
             {
                background-color: red;
                float: none;
             }
             #four
             {
                background-color: green;
                float: none;
             }

             </style>
             </HEAD>
             <BODY>
                   <div id="one" class="divs"> One </div>
                   <div id="two" class="divs"> Two</div>
                   <div id="three" class="divs"> Three </div>
                   <div id="four" class="divs"> Four </div>

             </BODY>
             </HTML>
```

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h2DHb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set them all to `float: left` and `clear: both` (or `clear: left`) the `#third` element.

```
.divs
{
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   float: left;
}
#one
{
   background-color: black;
   color: white;
}
#two
{
   background-color: blue;
}
#three
{
   background-color: red;
   clear: both;
}
#four
{
   background-color: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h2DHb/1/

Another alternative could be to make a `#container`, with the overall `height/width: 400px`, then set the `.divs` to be `height/width: 50%`:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one" class="divs"> One </div>
    <div id="two" class="divs"> Two</div>
    <div id="three" class="divs"> Three </div>
    <div id="four" class="divs"> Four </div>
</div>

#container {
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
}
.divs
{
   width: 50%;
   height: 50%;
   float: left;
}
#one
{
   background-color: black;
   color: white;
}
#two
{
   background-color: blue;
}
#three
{
   background-color: red;
   clear: left;
}
#four
{
   background-color: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h2DHb/2/

Answer (score 0):

Set a "width" for each element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `clear: right` in `#two` and `float: left;` in `#three` and `#four`. here is the corrected code :

```
<HTML>
          <HEAD>
          <TITLE>Layout Example</TITLE>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///C:/app3/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css">
          <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></SCRIPT>
          <style>
                 .divs
                 {
                    width: 200px;
                    height: 200px;
                 }
                 #one
                 {
                    background-color: black;
                    float: left;
                    color: white;
                 }
                 #two
                 {
                    background-color: blue;
                    float: left;                    
                 }
                 #three
                 {
                    background-color: red;
                    float: left;
                    clear: both;
                 }
                 #four
                 {
                    background-color: green;
                    float: left;
                 }

                 </style>
                 </HEAD>
                 <BODY>
                       <div id="one" class="divs"> One </div>
                       <div id="two" class="divs"> Two</div>
                       <div id="three" class="divs"> Three </div>
                       <div id="four" class="divs"> Four </div>

                 </BODY>
                 </HTML>
```

Comment: That `float: left` looks a little repetitive. Are you sure you have the `clear` on the right element?

Comment: yes you are right `float: left` looks repetitive but is there any problem with `clear: right`?

Comment: i am not sure but i think both do the same. I want no div is exists in right of `#two` similarly you want no div exists in left of `#three`. Is there any advantage?

Comment: Have a look at the first fiddle in my answer.

Comment: And then look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/h2DHb/3/ (and in fact it should be `clear: left` or `clear: both`).

Comment: didn't found any differences.